# Determination of a parameter in order to get a cdf.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $0<a<b$. Determine $p>0$ such that
>   $F(x)=(1-pe^{-ax}-(1-p)e^{-bx})I_{x\ge 0}$ is a distribution function.

The only assumption of a distribution function which could be violated by a freely chosen is that $F(x)$ has to be non-decreasing.

So thought it's a good idea to consider the density $f(x)=F'(x)$.
Hence
$f(x)=pae^{-ax}+b(1-p)e^{-bx}\ge0$.
But i think it's not possible to solve that.

Comment: The $f(x)$ is wrote is nonnegative for all $x$ as long as $0\le p\le 1$ (exponentials are positive). So there are many answers.

Comment: But how did you calculate that?

Comment: I didn't calculate, I just recognized a pattern. The pattern $p\cdot x+(1-p)\cdot y$ for $0\le p \le 1$, is common, and is a weighted average of $x$ and $y$. When $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, so is their weighted average. And it is common knowledge (in math) that exponentials are nonnegative.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But how did you find out that $f(x)<0 \quad \forall  p>1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is right. Any $p$ that satisfies $f(x) \ge 0$ can be used to represent the CDF, $F(x)$.

In order to determine the value of $p$, we define $c = p-\frac{b}{b-a}$. Observe that $$f(x) = \frac{ab}{b-a}\left(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}\right) + c\left(a e^{-ax}-be^{-bx}\right).$$
When $c \le 0$, $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$, whereas when $c>0$, $f(0) <0$. Consequently, $0 \le p \le \frac{b}{b-a}$.

Comment: $f(0)=pa+(1-p)b> pa+(1-p)a=a>0$ is positive for all $0\le p \le 1$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest $b/(b-a) > 1$.

Comment: Wow that is a great answer! Thank you!!